# Method to consume inputs before calling ‘input()’ using msvcrt on Mac

Tags: python, msvcrt

I am writing a programme in Python and have the following code to consume inputs before calling the `input()` function.

However, I don't think `msvcrt` is an available library on Mac. How could I convert this code to work on Mac:

```
def flush_input():
    try:
        import msvcrt
        while msvcrt.kbhit():
            msvcrt.getch()
    except ImportError:
        import sys, termios
        termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
```

Comment: The code already does what it needs to do. The `try` will fail if you are not on Windows, and instead falls back and tries to run code which should work on other platforms.

Comment: I get the following error: `termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')`

Comment: Are you not running it inside a terminal? It works for me. (But this code seems brittle and possibly useless anyway.)

Comment: Ah no, running it in PyCharm as part of a programme